# How to identify if a PDF file contains form fields

Tags: java, pdf, itext

We allow users to upload PDF documents for us to store. We warn the users that the PDF must be flattened before uploading, but many still upload PDF documents that contain form fields. We want to prevent this by validating the PDF file before uploading to our storage.

We are using iText-5.1 to read the file as a byte[] and open it with PdfReader. We then extract the fields with AcroFields() and test for existence. Currently the getFields().size() is always returning 0 *[see code below]*, even with a test PDF that I know contains form fields.

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(bytes);
AcroFields fields = reader.getAcroFields()
boolean hasFormFields = 
   (fields != null && fields.getFields() != null && fields.getFields().size() > 0);
if (hasFormFields) {
   // Report Error to User - throw exception, etc.
}
```

I would expect the getFields().size() to be larger than 0 when the PDF contains form field elements. Is there some other way to identify form fields using Java and iText?

Comment: The code you show should work for all acroform form elements. Is your example file a pure xfa form?

Comment: Another possibility is that you do the flatting incase there are form fields inside. But this probably depends on your users. (Some of our users don't have the ability to flatten their documents...)

Comment: @mkl How would I programmatically identify if the PDF file is "a pure xfa form"? Is that something in the META-Data that I would be able to read?

Comment: For checking for XFA use `fields.getXfa().isXfaPresent()`. For checking for AcroForm use your code. There is one other situation which you may want to avoid: Form field widget annotations referenced from pages while there is no **AcroForm** dictionary or only one without a **Fields** array or with only an empty **Fields** array. To check for them, you have to iterate over the document pages and check all their annotations' **Subtype** values.

Comment: It finally dawned on me - these PDF files are really XFA and that is why I can't find AcroForms. I added code to exclude XFA forms and that solves my problem. Thank you everyone for your help with this.

Answer (score 0):

You used the correct method to identify whether a (valid) PDF file contains form fields or not. The problem you describe is how to deal with non standard compliant PDF files which also contain form fields but do have some problems e.g. missing AcroField dictionary, a missing Fields array or others. You have three possibilities:

1. Ignore those cases since those are edge cases
2. Identify the problem (e.g. with Acrobat Preflight) and write a method to check
   for those cases. An example you find below where I wrote a method to
   identify documents with missing `Fields` array.
3. Just flatten all documents wich are uploaded.

The following code checks for documents where your method returns true but still contain form fields. Those fields would also be shown in *dobe reader.

```
   public boolean containsFormFields2() {

        AcroFields acroFields = reader.getAcroFields();

        if (acroFields.getFields() == null || acroFields.getFields().size() == 0) {
            // recheck "manually"
            for (int i = 1; i <= super.reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
                PdfDictionary page = super.reader.getPageN(i);
                PdfArray annots = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

                if (annots != null) {
                    // check for form fields in general
                    for (int j = 0; j < annots.size(); j++) {
                        PdfDictionary po2 = (PdfDictionary) annots.getDirectObject(j);

                        // FT key only exists for form fields
                        PdfName type = (PdfName) po2.get(PdfName.FT);
                        if (type != null) {
                           return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
         return false;
        }
        else{
         return true;
        }
   }
```

Comment: I have added this code to my method, and I get the same result ... size = 0. I really wish I could post the PDF, but the data is confidential. I'll see if I can get an example PDF that I can post. I do appreciate the help.

Comment: Is it only one PDF? Then I would think that it is buggy. There is obviously no Fields array. I changed the above code slightly. Can you execute it again and tell the result?

Comment: there have been about 4 dozen PDF files submitting in the last year that have this Form field issue. The reason it is a problem is due to the internal PDF viewer in Google Chrome. It is not able to display the file. Also, since the data is of a sensitive nature, we don't want to have editable data being stored. What I really want is to only accept flattened PDF files, but I am not aware of a good way to do that (this looking for form fields is really a hack to try to identify a non-flattened PDF file).

Comment: It might be a "hack" but it is quite well able to identify if there are non standard compliant PDFs. So I am curious: What was the output when you tried those 4 documents?

Comment: *"What I really want is to only accept flattened PDF files, but I am not aware of a good way to do that"* - how about flattening them yourself?

Comment: Which is possibility 3 in the above post :-)